# Protect joomla article with password

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla 1.5.21 website for a friend, he created a selling page for a program...and he wants to protect the page of the program , and send the password to everyone who purchases it.

So I've downloaded the contentPassword Plugin, and put the code : {password pass="123"} in the page I want protect.

When entering the page..the page asks me to enter password, but when I insert password, (123) it doesn't open the page.

My question is : is there someone whose familiar with this plugin? or is there any other better method that will save me more time?

thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using an SEF component ?

Comment: Standard warning - upgrade to 1.5.25, then get ready to upgrade to 2.5.x. The 1.5 series reaches end of life in April.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Mighty Membership. It limits access to articles, modules, components etc. Users can pay for a subscription which will allow them access to a specific article. You can also limit the amount of times they can view the page, so once they've paid, they can view the page once to download the software then it will be restricted again.

I've just used this to make a basic subscription only video site and it's pretty good.
Sadly it's not free though.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like to install plugins if it's not necessary. In your case I would add to the beginning of the article the following php code:

```
<?php
    $protect = $_GET['prot'];
    if ($protect != 'xR5dL0Nj76H'){
        //get out of here if you don't send the correct GET parameter...
        header('Location: http://www.google.com/'); 
    }
    //echo "logged in successfully!";
?>
```

and of course you'll have to send the users to the article with the GET parameter: &prot=xR5dL0Nj76H (its equivalent to have a shared password to all the users - like you describe)